# JavaScript HTML Object querySelectorAll search is difference when object is appended to element.

Tags: javascript

Got a strange issue at the moment, I currently have got an HTML Object generated from JSON code, now if I do a query search on this object like so:

```
var html = buildHTML(json);
html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]');
```

For some reason I only get 3 elements returned. However if I first append this to a div, and then to the same `querySelectorAll` search against this div's contents then I get all **4** elements like I should do.

```
var html = buildHTML(json);
document.getElementById('test').append(html);
document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('[data-click]');
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="marvLightbox" data-click="EventClose">
   <div class="marvLightbox__left" data-click="EventLeft"></div>
   <div class="marvLightbox__right" data-click="EventRight"></div>
   <div class="marvLightbox">
      <div class="marvLightbox__eschint">Press <span>ESC</span> to close</div>
      <div class="marvLightbox__close" data-click="EventClose"></div>
      <img src="https://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-with-jensen-beeler/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-cota-jensen-beeler-07.jpg" class="responsive-img image">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can see this in action here below.

```js
var json = `{
  "div": {
    "id": "marvLightbox",
    "data-click": "EventClose",
    "0": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__left",
        "data-click": "EventLeft"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__right",
        "data-click": "EventRight"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "div": {
        "0": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__eschint",
            "content": "Press <span>ESC</span> to close"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__close",
            "data-click": "EventClose"
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "img": {
            "src": "https://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-with-jensen-beeler/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-cota-jensen-beeler-07.jpg",
            "class": "responsive-img image"
          }
        },
        "class": "marvLightbox"
      }
    }
  }
}`;

function buildHTML(code) {
  "use strict";

  var handleAttribute = function(element, attribute, value) {
    if (value instanceof HTMLElement) {
      return element.appendChild(value);
    }

    switch (attribute) {
      case 'class':
      case 'src':
      case 'id':
      case 'data-click':
        return element.setAttribute(attribute, value);
      case 'content':
        return element.innerHTML = value;
        // other keys...
      default:
        console.log(element.tagName, attribute, value);
                     }
  }
  var htmlReviver = function(key, value) {
    // parse as element
    if (isNaN(key) && typeof value === 'object') {
      var element = document.createElement(key);
      var subValue;

      for (var attribute in value) {
        handleAttribute(element, attribute, value[attribute]);
      }

      return element;
      // move element from { index: { tagName: Element } } to { index: Element }
    } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
      return value[Object.keys(value)[0]];
      // leave property alone
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

  try {
    var htmlObject = JSON.parse(code, htmlReviver);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('marv.lightbox (Error): The HTML structure provided appears to have an error: ' + e);
  }

  return htmlObject;
}

(function() {
  var html = buildHTML(json);
  
  html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() { events(e.dataset.click); });
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML += 'Function: ' + e.dataset.click + ' Element: ' + e + '<br>';
  });
  
  document.getElementById('test').append(html);
}());
```

```css
body > div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id='debug'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are querying different element you are getting different result. Note `querySelectorAll()` returns the list of all **descended** elements.

In the following query `#marvLightbox` is not queried.

```
var html = buildHTML(json);
html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]');
```

```js
var json = `{
  "div": {
    "id": "marvLightbox",
    "data-click": "EventClose",
    "0": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__left",
        "data-click": "EventLeft"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__right",
        "data-click": "EventRight"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "div": {
        "0": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__eschint",
            "content": "Press <span>ESC</span> to close"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__close",
            "data-click": "EventClose"
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "img": {
            "src": "https://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-with-jensen-beeler/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-cota-jensen-beeler-07.jpg",
            "class": "responsive-img image"
          }
        },
        "class": "marvLightbox"
      }
    }
  }
}`;

function buildHTML(code) {
  "use strict";

  var handleAttribute = function(element, attribute, value) {
    if (value instanceof HTMLElement) {
      return element.appendChild(value);
    }

    switch (attribute) {
      case 'class':
      case 'src':
      case 'id':
      case 'data-click':
        return element.setAttribute(attribute, value);
      case 'content':
        return element.innerHTML = value;
        // other keys...
      default:
        console.log(element.tagName, attribute, value);
    }
  }
  var htmlReviver = function(key, value) {
    // parse as element
    if (isNaN(key) && typeof value === 'object') {
      var element = document.createElement(key);
      var subValue;

      for (var attribute in value) {
        handleAttribute(element, attribute, value[attribute]);
      }

      return element;
      // move element from { index: { tagName: Element } } to { index: Element }
    } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
      return value[Object.keys(value)[0]];
      // leave property alone
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

  try {
    var htmlObject = JSON.parse(code, htmlReviver);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('marv.lightbox (Error): The HTML structure provided appears to have an error: ' + e);
  }

  return htmlObject;
}

(function() {
  var html = buildHTML(json);
  html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  });

  console.log("For Whole document")
  document.getElementById('test').append(html);
  document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  });
}());
```

```css
body>div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <div id='debug'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah, how would I include this, just add an additional div before hand?

Comment: @MartynBall, Yes add an additional div, that would be simplest solution